# Does editing a post to remove a picture imply that it is clear?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Should one edit a post that they have marked unclear?

[Class action left handed lawsuit?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/42673/left-handed-lawsuit)

I keep getting pictures edited from my questions. They editor said that the pictures taking up more space then it contributes to the question.

The pictures are of standard size not limited by the SE System. If the picture is too big the system will not let it load. All pictures appear to me as the same size on my screen.

Does removing pictures from the question or answer free up disk space?

I can go back and revert the question to have the picture the way I had it. That tells me that the picture is still being stored somewhere. How long is data from edits stores?

Comment: Server disk space is not a consideration.  Readability – especially on smaller devices – definitely is, so photos that take up multiple vertical screens should be cropped and resized if possible.

Comment: @feetwet is this the main issue?  I can make sure they are small from now on.

Comment: That's my best guess: From what I have seen in general, relevant pictures add a lot to posts and are well received.  In the case of your referenced question: the picture dwarfed the question itself in terms of screen space, and it wasn't even clear how it was relevant to the question until many edits in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A post may be edited to make it more clear or improve it in any way, or to remove irrelevant details, particularly images which take up much space and may not add much to the question. Editing does not imply acceptance of the question as clear or acceptable, merely as improved.

Comment: Even if data is deleted it is still stored data and does not "free up space" as some may think.

Comment: How long does past edits data stick in the hard drive of SE servers? Removing the picture only made it less unclear.

Comment: @muze It may not free up any space on the server, where all that is stored is a link anyway, i think. It does reduce the amount of data sent to a reader, and the amount of screen space taken up by the displayed question for a reader. It may also remove a copyright issue in some cases.

Comment: I edited this question and thanks for helping but I just cannot see how removing the picture, closing, and down voting helps me or SE in anyway.

Comment: It is my view that the picture added nothing useful to the question, and I would also have removed the image. Closing the question is a different matter.

Comment: What would be the best way to show a right handed classroom?

Comment: @muze there is no need to show anything. That many things are oriented to a right-handed majority is already well known.  An image only records this well-known fact. If you **must** have an image, include a link to a site with the image, do not include the image in the question. I am about to remove the image again.

Comment: Not to argue but links to pictures are less stable than pictures. I explained how discrimination was common by using the picture. In your defense a thousand words instead of a picture would take less disk space.